# Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied in android application

Tags: java, android, shell, adb

my question is after adding su in command it throws the following error:
 Cannot run program "su": error=13, Permission denied in android application

Comment: Maybe the device is not rooted and thus cannot use the superuser?

Comment: `su` is pretty much to execute superuser commands. You can't run it without providing, on unix systems at least, a password or already being the superuser.

Answer (score 4):

You need to root your smartphone not just to copy the binary of su. 
So root your smartphone installing a root access management tool like SuperSu

Answer (score -1):

I got it working by executing in shell:

```
chmod 755 /system/xbin/su
```

Comment: Do not execute that as you will loose "su" access on current user.
Recover using
adb root
mount -o rw,remount /
chmod 4750 /system/xbin/su
reboot

Comment: i replaced the su with the one from koush's supersu, setting chmod 06755 worked for me.